# Why is Stackage currently stuck on cabal 1.18?

Tags: haskell, cabal, stackage

At the moment (Oct 24th, 2014) cabal 1.18 ships with Stackage, while cabal 1.20 is out since April 2014.  I expect there is a reason for this: I'm curious to what that reason may be and hope that by this question I can get it out on a place that Google indexes.

Comment: Have you sent an email to to the Stackage maintainers?

Comment: @Zeta, nope I have not.  I know the Michael and others are on top of this site, and otherwise I had to mail them and write a blog post on it in order to have Google index it (and my blog will probably rank worse then this site).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the `ghc` package- which cannot be upgraded- depends on `Cabal-1.18`. For more information, see https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2014/05/lenient-lower-bounds. For the same reason, Haskell Platform ships with Cabal 1.18, and GHC 7.10 is trying to get rid of the Cabal dependency in the `ghc` package (and, AFAIK, that's already landed in HEAD).

Comment: Thanks Michael, once again.  Now Google, c'mon and index this! :)

Comment: [Reference in a Reddit thread on the GHC-Cabal-HaskellPlatform version lock](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2d3p2c/haskell_platform_2014200_is_released/cjm4xtp)